# BAPI for adding descriptions to Master Changes?

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-erp

I have a program that will automatically change or creates the BOM using the BAPI.

When you change, you enter the change number (`AEOI-AENNR`), but add a description of the change (`AEOI-OITXT`) there is no possibility. Now I prescribe them manually using transaction CC02. Who knows any function modules or BAPI to automatic change of data in the Master Changes to automatic after I change the specifications could automatically add a description.

EDIT (from OP comment): "The specification used CSAP_BOM_ITEM_MAINTAIN, BAPI_MATERIAL_BOM_GROUP_CREATE. They serve a number of changes, but the description for the field AEOI-OITXT have not seen."

Comment: Welcome to SO! What FM do you use?

Comment: The specification used CSAP_BOM_ITEM_MAINTAIN, BAPI_MATERIAL_BOM_GROUP_CREATE.
They serve a number of changes, but the description for the field AEOI-OITXT have not seen.

Answer (score 1):

'BAPI_ISMCHANGENUMBER_CREATE' should work to create the change number, validity date, and description.

Then simply assign that number (given in return data) to the BOM bapi call.